# How to extract double int value from excel sheet using selenium

Tags: excel, selenium

Following is the code I used for extracting any value from excel sheet. Cell value can be string ,date or long int. Using below code I am able to extract string and date correctly but long int values are coming in as 4.6861230317E10 instead of 46861230317. How to overcome this issue??

```
 Cell = ExcelWSheet.getRow(RowNum).getCell(ColNum); 
                if(Cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING)
                {

                    System.out.println("check for celltype string");
                    CellData = Cell.getStringCellValue();
                    System.out.println("String CellData:"+CellData);
                }   
                else  
                if(Cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC)
                {
                    System.out.println("checking for celltype numeric");
                    CellData = fmt.formatCellValue(Cell);
                    if(CellData.contains("/"))
                    {
                        System.out.println("its a date !"+CellData);
                    }
                    else if(!CellData.contains("/"))
                    {

                        double  CellData2 = (double)Cell.getNumericCellValue(); 
                        System.out.println("actual double value "+CellData2);
                        CellData=String.valueOf(CellData2);
                        System.out.println("its a double int numeric value "+CellData);

                    }

                }   
                System.out.println("returning cell data "+CellData);
                return CellData;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following line implementation in your code

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
double  CellData2 = (double)Cell.getNumericCellValue();
```

use

```
long CellData2 = new Double(Cell.getNumericCellValue()).longValue();
```

It works just fine too !!!